Compiled Javascript files in yarn workspace are not in dist folder but next to corresponding typescipt files
I have a yarn workspace . When compiling typescript code , javascript files are next to typescript files not in the dist folder .
tsconfig.json in the root of the workspace

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2020",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["node_modules/*", "packages/*"],
      "@/types/*": ["packages/types/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}

and this is tsconfig.json of  a package in the workspace
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./"
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", "scripts/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.test.ts"]
}



I want all the compiled javascript files should be in the dist folder
